# Custom attributes for a DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created new `TimeDialogPreference` that extends `DialogPreference`.

In `preferences.xml` I have:

```
<info.chrzanowski.project.preference.TimeDialogPreference
    android:key="recordTime"
    android:id="@+id/recordTime"
    android:title="title"
    android:summary="summary"
    step="5"
    />
```

How can I access from `TimeDialogPreference` class that `step` attribute ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found solution here: http://www.androidapps.org/passing-custom-attributes-via-xml-resource-files

Answer (score 8):

The attributes are passed to the constructor of your custom preference:

Check out the AttributeSet class for other ways to dig out the value, for example:

```
public TimeDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    for (int i=0;i<attrs.getAttributeCount();i++) {
        String attr = attrs.getAttributeName(i);
        String val  = attrs.getAttributeValue(i);
        if (attr.equalsIgnoreCase("step")) {
            Log.i("TimeDialogPreference", "step = "+val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible without looping all attributes ?

Comment: AttributeSet Docs are here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html

Comment: `attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "step")`